# SFML c++ program throws an error "Entry point not found" when running

Tags: c++, g++, sfml

I recently started learning c++ and now I'm somewhat familiar with c++. But this is my first SFML program and I don't have any experience using third party libraries. I made my first SFML program to open a window. But it doesn't run and throws an error.

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main() {
    sf::Window playground = sf::Window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "Sanke");

    while (playground.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;

        while (playground.pollEvent(event)) {
            switch (event.type) {
                case sf::Event::Closed:
                playground.close();
                break;
            }
        }

        playground.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I created a bat file to run this.

**main.bat**

```
@echo off

g++ main.cpp -o main.exe -IC:/Users/USER/Desktop/project/SFML-2.5.1/include -LC:/Users/USER/Desktop/project/SFML-2.5.1/lib -lsfml-system -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-audio -lsfml-network

main.exe
```

Then I placed all the dll files in the sfml/bin/ to the project directory. When I run the main.bat file It throws out this error.

```
main.exe - Entry Point Not Found

The procedure entry point
_ZNSt15basic_streambuflcSt11char_traitslcEE7seekposESt4fpo
sliEST13_los_Openmode could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\Users\User\Desktop\project\sfml-system-2.dll
```

I searched this up for hours. But I have no idea how to fix this. Even followed some tutorials. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a dll conflict. You most likely have more than 1 version of your MinGW dlls in the folders of your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: ***Then I placed all the dll files in the sfml/bin/ to the project directory.*** Where did you get these dlls? Were they built for MinGW? Remember msvc dlls are not compatible.

Comment: The easiest way to get proper binaries for SFML is to install both MinGW and SFML using the package manager `pacman` in msys2.  This way you are sure that you have compatible dlls and not ones for `msvc` (Microsoft's compiler)  which are not compatible.

Comment: I got the .dll s from the sfml-2.5.1/bin folder. I'm using mingw compiler from msys. Compiler path is c:/msys64/ucrt64/bin . And I downloaded the "SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit" frim sfml website. The problem perisists even after removing .dll s from the project directory.

Comment: I freshly downloaded the sfml and mingw64 again from the urls provided in sfml website. Now the program works fine. But c++ standard library headers are misding from mingw64.

Comment: ***But c++ standard library headers are misding from mingw64*** Did you use msys2 to install MinGW? If you did not my advice is to do so. If you use VSCode the official VSCode / MinGW documentation tells you to use msys2 to install MinGW.

Comment: I had previously installed mingw from msys. After getting error, I used the mingw compiler downloaded from the link in sfml website. But that one doesn't have c++ stl headers. I need to include the sfml library in my project directory. How can I find the compettible sfml version for my compiler. Should I use pacman.

Comment: If you use msys2 to install MinGW then use pacman to install SFML it should all work with no problems.  Besides the extra step the problem with binary downloads is they are for specific compilers and specific compiler versions. If you are not using the version and compiler that the library was compiled for you can have incompatibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Program worked after adding c++ standard(std=c++17) to the compiler command

```
g++ main.cpp -o main.exe -IC:/Users/USER/Desktop/project/SFML-2.5.1/include -LC:/Users/USER/Desktop/project/SFML-2.5.1/lib -lsfml-system -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-audio -lsfml-network -std=c++17
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your dll files are in the correct folder. You can find information where to put the dll files on the official SFML website https://www.sfml-dev.org/

Also make sure you create the window using the constructor like below rather than your way. This was also an error that crashed the program. after these changes compiling with g++ on both linux and windows works. Also it would be great if you added the window.hpp file just to be sure. If problems are still there, it's most likely a problem with your include path, lib path or dlls path (in short the linking of the files)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
int main() {
    sf::Window playground(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "Sanke");

    while (playground.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;

        while (playground.pollEvent(event)) {
            switch (event.type) {
                case sf::Event::Closed:
                playground.close();
                break;
            }
        }

        playground.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```